# Could an array or two, solve this?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I took over a project and I'm really new to as3! I need to fix an unresolved problem hopefully without starting over from scratch.

I have a contaner_mc, holding four puppet_mc's (`puppet_mc1`, `puppet_mc2`, `puppet_mc3`, `puppet_mc4`) and each puppet_mc holds four buttons (`buddy_bnt_1`, `buddy_bnt_2`, `buddy_bnt_3`, `buddy_bnt_4`).

I need the listener to know what button was clicked and from what puppet that button was clicked?

```
Object(this).contaner_mc.puppet_mc?.buddy_bnt_?.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_Click);

function fl_Click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(15);
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event bubbling should to the magic:

```
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_handler);

function click_handler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  if (event.currentTarget == event.target) {
    return; // the container is the dispatcher
  }

  const sprite:Sprite = event.target as Sprite; // just for a typing
  if (!sprite) {
    trace("event.target is no sprite, set break point here for debugging.");
    return;
  }

  if (sprite.name == 'buddy_bnt_1' || sprite.name == 'puppet_mc1') {
    // do something
  } else if (sprite.name == 'buddy_bnt_2' || sprite.name == 'puppet_mc2') {
    // do something different
  } else if (sprite.name == 'buddy_bnt_3' || sprite.name == 'puppet_mc3') {
    // do something different
  } else if (sprite.name == 'buddy_bnt_4' || sprite.name == 'puppet_mc4') {
    // do something different
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! but I get this Error  TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at chatV3_fla::MainTimeline/click_handler()

Comment: It appears that the cast to sprite is broken. Do you use an image as button?

Comment: I enhanced the script to check if the Bitmap's parent is the dispatcher. Please use breakpoints to confirm the dispatcher's identity.

Answer (score 0):

```
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clickedObject:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;

    trace (clickedObject.name);   // name of button clicked
    trace (clickedObject.parent.name);  // name of the parent
}
```

I used DisplayObject so that the code would work with a sprite , movieclip, or any DisplayObject. So make sure you import if you haven't already :

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
```